# Codec not found for requested operation [decimal <-> java.lang.Double]

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, codec, datastax-java-driver

I have decimal value in Cassandra db how to get that value

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("dev").withPort(9042).build();
   cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry().register(InstantCodec.decimal());
    Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from("app");
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

    ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(select);

    Map<String,Map<String,Long>>map = new HashMap();

   resultSet.forEach(x ->map.put(x.getString("signal_name"),x.getMap("config",String.class,Long.class)));
```

Comment: could you update your original questions with information regarding the driver groupId, artifactId and version of the dependencies in your project? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess around with the codecs.  This error is occurring because the Cassandra `DECIMAL` type does not map to a Java `Double`.

Let's assume that I have a table of numeric types, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE numerics (
    num INT PRIMARY KEY,
    dec DECIMAL,
    doub DOUBLE,
    flt FLOAT);
```

With the query builder, I can query and map these types like this:

```
Select query = QueryBuilder.selectFrom("stackoverflow", "numerics")
    .column("num")
    .column("dec")
    .column("doub")
    .column("flt")
    .whereColumn("num")
        .isEqualTo(QueryBuilder.literal(1));
SimpleStatement statement = query.build();

ResultSet rs = session.execute(statement);
Row row = rs.one();
          
System.out.println("num(int) = " + row.getInt("num"));
System.out.println("decimal = " + row.getBigDecimal("dec"));
System.out.println("double = " + row.getDouble("doub"));
System.out.println("float = " + row.getFloat("flt"));
```

**tl;dr;**

A Cassandra `DECIMAL` type maps to a `BigDecimal`, so try using that.

Github repo: https://github.com/aar0np/SelectNumerics

Answer (score 0):

A `decimal` CQL data type maps to `BigDecimal` in java type. See [CQL to Java type mapping documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) for more details.

Having said that, here is what I did with an example where I leveraged **DataStax Astra DB** to demonstrate this:

**Table Structure**:

```
CREATE TABLE ks.sodecimal (
    i int PRIMARY KEY,
    j decimal
);
```

**Data**:

```
token@cqlsh:ks> SELECT * FROM sodecimal ;

 i | j
---+-------
 1 | 0.124

(1 rows)
```

**Java Driver**:
I'm using [DataStax Java Driver `4.15.0` version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.oss/java-driver-core/4.15.0) which is the latest as of this writing.

```
...
System.out.println("-----------");
ResultSet rs_dec = session.execute("SELECT j FROM ks.sodecimal WHERE i = 1");
BigDecimal bd = rs_dec.one().getBigDecimal("j");
System.out.println("Decimal value: " + bd.toString());
System.out.println("-----------");
...
```

**Output**:

```
-----------
Decimal value: 0.124
-----------
```